# org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: Valuetype does not implement StreamableValue or CustomMarshal

Tags: java, websphere-liberty, corba, orb

I am trying to call a remote EJB service(MDM service) using Liberty profile 16.0.0.3. My lookup code looks like below.

```
ctx = new InitialContext();
Object obj = 
        ctx.lookup("corbaname:iiop:myhost:9810/NameServiceServerRoot#com/dwl/base/requestHandler/beans/DWLServiceController");
        dwlServiceControllerHome = (DWLServiceControllerHome)PortableRemoteObject.narrow(obj, DWLServiceControllerHome.class);
        dwlServiceController = dwlServiceControllerHome.create();
        HashMap<String, String> contextMap = createContextMap();

        String response = dwlServiceController.processRequest(contextMap, wccReqString).toString().trim();  
                            try {
                                StringReader reader = new StringReader(response);                   
                                StreamSource streamSource = new StreamSource(reader);
                                tcrmResp = (TCRMService) providerMarshaller.unmarshal(streamSource);
                            } catch (Exception e) {

                                e.printStackTrace();

                                throw e;
                            }
```

With above code I can able to call remote EJB service.Positive scenario is working without any issue.When we test the service with negative scenario data(When remote EJB service throw Custom valid exceptions)  getting below error.

```
[ERROR   ] MARSHAL "Valuetype does not implement StreamableValue or CustomMarshal", at pos=0x214
[err] org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: Valuetype does not implement StreamableValue or CustomMarshal:  vmcid: 0x0 minor code: 0x0  completed: No
[err]   at org.apache.yoko.orb.OB.ValueReader.unmarshalValueState(ValueReader.java:716)
[err]   at org.apache.yoko.orb.OB.ValueReader.access$300(ValueReader.java:54)
[err]   at org.apache.yoko.orb.OB.ValueReader$ClassCreationStrategy.create(ValueReader.java:196)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   at java.lang.Throwable.readObject(Throwable.java:388)
[err]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[err]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
[err]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
[err]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
[err]   at org.apache.yoko.rmi.impl.ValueDescriptor.readSerializable(ValueDescriptor.java:735)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   at org.apache.yoko.orb.OB.ValueReader.access$200(ValueReader.java:54)
[err]   at org.apache.yoko.orb.OB.ValueReader$ClassCreationStrategy.create(ValueReader.java:189)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   at com.dwl.base.requestHandler.beans._DWLServiceController_Stub.processRequest(_DWLServiceController_Stub.java:1001)
```

We are using below technology specifications

- Spring Boot 1.2.4/1.4.2
- Liberty Profile 16.0.0.3
- IBM JDK 8/Sun JDK 8

Comment: I added some basic formatting to your question to make it easier to read. Please review Stack Overflow's [formatting guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) so you can do this yourself next time.

Answer (score 0):

"org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL" says it all. Definitions (IDLs) of interfaces on both sides must be identical. Marshalling error happens exactly if they are not. Probably your code does not have a definition for exception returned or definition differs from the one on the remote side.

Comment: I am calling MDM Infospeher remote EJB.Same code is working fine in traditional WebSphere application server.When I deploy the code in Liberty 16.0.0.3 I am getting the error.Did I am missing any server specific jar or is it something related to JDK?Is there any way I can able debug logging and capture response Object from Remote EJB?

Comment: The IDLs are probably different in these two cases. The server just uses different IDL than you are. Many times it is slight version difference, in some newer version some parameters might be added/removed or have different type.

Comment: The IDLs are compiled into Java code, so you can't do much on the server side except to change the code, what is probably not an option.
What you can do is use the same IDLs as on server and compile them for your code. Maybe you can find those ".idl" files somewhere on the server, search for same or similar file names as IDLs you are using have.

Comment: In traditional webSpeher this orb.idl file is in JDK.I have pointed to same JDK and executed my code with Liberty profile.But still getting same error.

Comment: But there's another IDL for Liberty I presume?
And your code needs to be recompiled from IDL in case of IDL changes.
The best way is to copy exactly the same file from server, not to point to appropriate one in JDK. They could be slightly different.